# Copying entire gadget of a website

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogger

I am new to web design so I wanted to learn more by looking at other websites and using their techniques. Now I am currently using blogger platform and wanted to copy an entire gadget from another blog http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/. I am trying to copy the right floating sidebar gadget to by blog.

To do so, I think I will have to copy the CSS codes, html codes and javascript if it is used. Is there a simple way to find all those codes and copy those to mine? I did try using the inspect element function of google chrome but was unsuccessful.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Inspection elements are probably your best way to go, but a decent grasp of CSS and HTML would be required to get you started on that. Toggling styles on and off to see what happens is a good way to start poking into existing solutions.

When it comes to JavaScript parts of a feature, the inspection tools will probably not get you all that far.

For deeper introspection, you could always save a local copy of the entire webpage, remove bits and pieces, and see at which points the feature breaks; keep the things that seem to be required, and continue until you seem to have stripped the site down to the bare minimum to keep your feature working. From there you can move on to see if you can understand what the different parts of the remaining code does.

For your specific gadget, some key aspects include:

- `#gadget-dock` has the style `position: fixed` that keeps the element's position in place as the user scrolls up and down the page.
- `#gadget-dock` has the style `right: -40px` which keeps the element all but out of sight, by default.
- `#gadget-dock:hover` has the style `right: 0` which overrides the aforementioned style and moves the element into sight when hovered.
- `#gadget-dock` also have a lot of CSS3 *transitions* that define the sliding motions that appear when changing from one position to another (i.e. when the value for `right` is changed).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions. But it sounds real difficult to me at this time. So I think I will learn more about coding before moving on. Also, do you have any other ideas for finding the javascript? 

Thanks a lot once again.

Comment: I did try copying the codes here http://empireswiki.blogspot.com/, but it is not working well. Do you have any ideas to improve it?

Comment: @John: In the page you've linked to there are a couple of script tags that are not being closed properly. Your inspection tools will help you identify the lines of code where this is happening. As for your gadget not working, you won't need JavaScript to achieve the basic functionality there. You're missing the `#gadget-dock:hover` styles, at least, which will be required.